# Trouble Removing Plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax, login

I'm editing this site http://www.millermusicproductions.com/ currently and I am trying to get rid of the login in the upper-right corner. I go to plugins and deactivate a plugin called "Login with AJAX", then I refresh the page and only the page's header displays.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any sort of cacheing?

Comment: Not sure...I don't really know much about WP, just trying to figure it out as I go along. If the default is no caching, then probably not. @m0r7if3r

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that do cacheing? Something like W3 Total Cache, Supercache, or Hypercache? It very well may be that those fields are hardcoded into the theme.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Not hardcoded into the theme, here's his other site: http://www.millermusiclessons.com/ I'll check the plugins now.

Comment: http://imgur.com/udsFS http://imgur.com/GOjOZ <-all the plugins

Comment: This is a *user-support* question, that might be better-served at the [official wordpress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the function for showing the Ajax login is still in the theme header.php

You can look for the function login_with_ajax() in your themes header.php and remove it, if it's there.

If an undefined function is called you get a fatal error and the script will stop. So it only displays until the function, in your case the end of your header.